# Incomplete HTML is rendered on some Ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF along with primefaces most of the time application works fine but sometimes on primefaces tabview tab change incorrect xhtml is returned from the server here is the resposne.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partial-response>
  <changes>
    <update id="mainPageHeaderFormId:navigationPanel"><![CDATA[<span id="mainPageHeaderFormId:navigationPanel" class="navigationPanelClass"></span>]]></update>
    <update id="tabView"><![CDATA[<form id="tabView:basicSearchFormId" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId" method="post" action="/falcon-uip/secured/main/index.faces?windowId=2d8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId" value="tabView:basicSearchFormId" />
    <script id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchPanelDivId_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Layout","widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchPanelDivId",{id:"tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchPanelDivId",widgetVar:"widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchPanelDivId",west:{paneSelector:'#tabView\\:basicSearchFormId\\:basicSearchWest',size:"325",resizable:true,closable:true,minSize:220,maxSize:350,spacing_open:0,spacing_closed:25},center:{paneSelector:'#tabView\\:basicSearchFormId\\:basicSearchSecondId1',size:"auto",resizable:false,closable:false}},"layout");});</script><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchPanelDivId" style="border-style:hidden;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:top;             height:576px;min-width:100%;margin:0 0 0 0;"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchWest" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-west" style="border-style:hidden; width:200px; padding:0px"><div class="ui-layout-unit-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-layout-unit-header-title">Search Panel</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-layout-unit-header-icon ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Collapse"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-w"></span></a></div><div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container" role="tablist" data-widget="widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion"><h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Basic Search</h3><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelCollapsibleId1" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelCentreId1" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="border-style:hidden; width:100%; padding:0px; overflow: scroll;" data-widget="widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_basicSearchPanelCentreId1"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelCentreId1_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content"><table id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchQueryPanelGroupId1" style="width:100%; border-style:hidden;  margin-left: 0px">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><table id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchChkBoxPanelGrid" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" role="grid"><tbody><tr class="ui-widget-content ui-panelgrid-even" role="row"><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell" style="border-style:hidden;"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget"><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1_input" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1_input" type="checkbox" /></div><div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span></div></div><script id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("SelectBooleanCheckbox","widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1",{id:"tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1",widgetVar:"widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_basicSearchHistoryCheckBoxId1"});</script><span id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivOT" style="vertical-align:40%;"> Search History</span></td><td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell" style="border-style:hidden;"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget"><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB_input" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB_input" type="checkbox" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB',e:'valueChange',p:'tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB',u:'tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:textDataTypesPaneld'});" /></div><div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span></div></div><script id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("SelectBooleanCheckbox","widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_basicSearchPanelDivSBCB",{id:"tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:basicSearchPanelDivSBCB",widgetVar:"widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_basicSearchPanelDivSBCB"});</script><span style="vertical-align:40%;"> Search Drafts</span></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38" class="ui-datagrid ui-widget"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38_content" class="ui-datagrid-content ui-widget-content"><table class="ui-datagrid-data"><tbody><tr class="ui-datagrid-row"><td class="ui-datagrid-column"><div id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu" class="ui-selectcheckboxmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="width:100%"><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu_focus" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu_focus" type="text" readonly="readonly" /></div><div class="ui-helper-hidden"><input id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu:0" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu" type="checkbox" value="Open" checked="checked" /><label for="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu:0">Open</label><input id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu:1" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu" type="checkbox" value="Closed" checked="checked" /><label for="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu:1">Closed</label></div><a href="#" class="ui-selectcheckboxmenu-label-container"><label class="ui-selectcheckboxmenu-label ui-corner-all">Status</label></a><div class="ui-selectcheckboxmenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></div></div><script id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("SelectCheckboxMenu","widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_j_idt38_0_optionMenu",{id:"tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38:0:optionMenu",widgetVar:"widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_j_idt38_0_optionMenu",filter:true,filterMatchMode:"startsWith",panelStyle:"width:250px"});});</script></td><td class="ui-datagrid-column"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><script id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("DataGrid","widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_j_idt38",{id:"tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt38",widgetVar:"widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_j_idt38"});</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><table id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:textDataTypesPaneld" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="leftAlignColumn"><label style="text-align:right;">
    Description:</label></td>
    <td class=" leftAlignColumn"><input id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt41" name="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt41" type="text" value="" style="width: 90%;" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all dateUIClass" /><script id="tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt41_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("InputText","widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_j_idt41",{id:"tabView:basicSearchFormId:basicSearchAccordion:j_idt41",widgetVar:"widget_tabView_basicSearchFormId_basicSearchAccordion_j_idt41"});</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="leftAlignColumn"><label style="text-align:right;">
    Last Update By.:</label></td>
    <td class=" leftAlignColumn">]]></update>
    <update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-5426755969360895859:3636598073341851124]]></update>
    <eval><![CDATA[loadFalconDialogs();]]></eval>
  </changes>
</partial-response>
```

As you can see at the end the `<td class=" leftAlignColumn">` tag is left open.

***Edit***

Versions

> Primefaces 5.0
>   Jsf - 2.2.1

Also glassfish is used as server. There are no exceptions thrown or any error shown in log.

Comment: It can help to state which version of Primefaces you're actually using.

Comment: primefaces 5.0 and Jsf 2.2.1

Comment: Looks like a fairly large response. Assuming there's nothing fundamentally broken with the implementations, set `javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE` to `4172` in your web.xml (or even `-1`) to remove the limit on the response size and then see what happens

Comment: i already have javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE set to 1048560.

Comment: So try with Primefaces 5.1, it would be a shame if you're running into a bug that has already been fixed.